# How to update from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS in Terminal

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, updates, downloads

I have a dual boot 12.04 LTS and windows 7, now i want to update from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS, how to do this in terminal? and also how many MB of data it takes approximately?

If any disturbance is occured while upadting (i mean disconnection in WiFi) will it starts downloads from beginning? or it continues from where it stops?

Answer (score 0):

**Back up your important data before you start any such thing.**

Type the following command to update package list and instal the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Next, type the following command to upgrade the Ubuntu server to the latest release such as LTS 14.04 from the command-line. This is the recommended command as the server has no graphic environment or if the server is to be upgraded over a remote connection using ssh client:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

The do-release-upgrade will launch the upgrade tool. You need to follow the on-screen instructions.